# Creating a new email from iPhone/iPad default settings pane?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings.bundle, root.plist

Is it possible to add an "Email A Developer" section within Apple's default settings bundle for an iOS application?

Use Case:

From the global settings pane of my app, I would like a user to be able to select "Email A Developer" and have that launch a new email pre-populated with the developers email address and a default message title.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think it's possible in a settings.bundle yet.  Remember, apple always keeps the coolest features for themselves.

Comment: I figured that would be the case :) Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute your own code from within the settings app, so this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: He wants to put it in the settings app, so no, it's not possible.

Comment: Oh, from the standard Settings app? I missed that part. No, probably not.